# using matplotlib /plotly to make an histogram

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plotly

I have to realize a histogram using matplotlip and plotly. But I am stuck because there are so many options available and with so don't manage to have a proper histogram with all the online tutorials.
My data is a matrix of two columns and 20000 rows. I use those commands, but it didn't work.

here is my code:

```
with open('rmsd.dat') as f:
       v = np.loadtxt(f, delimiter= ' ')
plt.hist(v, bins=100)
plt.xlabel("G-r0")
plt.ylabel('# of stars')
plt.title("RMSD histogramm")

plt.show()
```

In a second time the histogram has to be horizontal and near another plot using the same data 
I tried to use matplotlib and plotly but it was a big mess

that all

Comment: sorry, how is your data? Is one column your values and second column your frequency? When you do `plt.hist(v)` it calculates the histogram from your array. May be you should look into `histogram2d` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html`

Comment: "it didn't work" is not useful. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and include the errors you see or what you see and what you expect to see.

Answer (score 1):

Your data has two columns, so you must to indicate which column you want to plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data[:,0] #shape (3000,2)
plt.hist(data[:,0],bins=100)
```

[Example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5iCd.png)

Or horizontal:

```
plt.hist(data[:,0],bins=100,orientation='horizontal')
```

If I just use `plt.hist(data,bins=30)` it will appear like a simple bar plot.

[Example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JK3mG.png)